# Getting the admin chosen attribute for a variatioan

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am trying to get the chosen attribute for a variation.
For example, i got a shoes product, with some variations. each variation has color and width attributes.
The website admin set few variations, on each variation he have chosen different color and width.

I am creating a report, and I need to get these chosen values for each variation. but it seems to be impossible.

I'm looping through products, and on each product I'm looping through its variations.

```
 $products = new WP_Query( $args ) ;

    if ( $products->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
            $product = new WC_Product($post->ID);
            $product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($post->ID);
```

Now... what should I use to get these chosen values. The attributes are saved under pa_color and pa_width .
I have tried using **$product_variation->get_attribute** and **get_attributes** but none return the chosen values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK Problem solved:

```
$variation_meta   = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

$pa_color = $variation_meta['attribute_pa_color'];
$pa_width = $variation_meta['attribute_pa_width'];
```